# oracle-java8-installer results in "apt" removal?

Tags: apt, java

I have been been running trusty since the first alpha release, pulling daily updates. I also installed the oracle-java7-installer from the WebUpd8 PPA.  Today I noticed during a dist-upgrade that oracle-java7-installer was being removed.  On my edge system I just allow all the defaults so I allowed the removal expecting to try out the java 8 version anyway.  However when I went to install the oracle-java8-installer package it wanted to remove "apt"!?  This obviously sparked my concern, as it even feels like a security concern.  Help understanding this would be greatly appreciated.

```
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  visualvm ttf-baekmuk ttf-unfonts ttf-unfonts-core ttf-kochi-gothic ttf-sazanami-gothic ttf-kochi-mincho ttf-sazanami-mincho
  ttf-arphic-uming
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apt apturl nautilus-share python3-software-properties software-center software-properties-common software-properties-gtk
  ubuntu-extras-keyring ubuntu-minimal unattended-upgrades
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  oracle-java8-installer
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  apt
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 10 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 18.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7,838 kB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
 ?]
```

Comment: Please Don't do that.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I think he knows that. :) @Lance: I suspect it was something in the `apt-get dist-upgrade` that is causing this problem, as the installer package has very few dependencies and one conflict, and `oracle-java7-installer` shouldn't have been removed.

Comment: @saiarcot895 _one conflict_, which one?

Comment: Try to hold all the important packages shown above and then try to install `oracle-java8-installer` package.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: `j2se-common`

Comment: This should not occur, please report a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys.  @AvinashRaj, you are correct I know better :), also as a rule I do my updates on my edge system first and only perform the operations suggested by my package manager; waiting (within reason) for issues to be fixed before applying updates to my main system. So I'll track the bug reported by AndyS.  Thanks again guys.

Comment: any update on this? I'm still encountering the "Yes, do as I say!" prompt

Comment: @binnyb the bug reported to launchpad.net I believe has been fixed.

Comment: Moderator.  This issue is on topic and is directly related to Ubuntu.  Also a bug was reported almost immediately upon me asking the question.  I am an active participant in the Ubuntu and StackExchange communities. I asked this question wishing to learn from my peers about and aspect of Ubuntu development. I submit that the very nature of this question is the reason this site exists. I investigated the help center rules and this question is within the guidelines. In my opinion placing questions such as these on hold actively discourages involvement in the community.  Please reconsider.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This recent change referenced in the 'apt' package ChangeLog appears to be the likely culprit:

```
apt (0.9.15.4ubuntu4) trusty; urgency=low

  Cherry pick fixes from the apt 1.0 branch:

  [ Michael Vogt ]
  * add sun-java{5,6}-jdk to breaks/replaces as that provided a "apt"
    binary as well
```

The oracle-java8-installer package "Provides" the "sun-java6-jdk" package, so this conflict bubbles up and prevents us from installing the WebUpd8 packages -- even though neither oracle-java7-installer nor oracle-java8-installer actually installs the problematic "apt" binary mentioned in the apt changelog.

I went ahead and submitted a bug report for this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1302736

Answer (score 7):

Andy S has the underlying problem here and I'd expect a fix out soon.  Please use the bug report link he provided and indicate that it also affects you so that it gains higher priority.

If you absolutely can't wait, here's a temporary workaround to ignore the dependency issues and force the install:

- Download the .deb package from apt `sudo apt-get download oracle-java7-installer`
- Do the install of the .deb you just downloaded, ignoring any dependencies apt complains about: `sudo dpkg -i --ignore-depends=apt file-you-just-downloaded.deb`

Two items of note:

1. you can use this similarly for Java 8 by changing the commands above accordingly.
2. For at least the time being, your apt will think it has a broken dependency and request removing oracle-java7-installer.  You can revert back by using `apt-get -f install`.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround until this gets fixed is to modify the deb file from webupd8 and remove `sun-java6-jdk` from the `Provides` line in the deb control file. There's a handy script in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/311621) on superuser.com. Just grab the [original file](http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/pool/main/o/oracle-java8-installer/oracle-java8-installer_8u0-1~webupd8~5_all.deb), run the script on it, modify the `Provides` line and install the modified file with `sudo dpkg -i`.

I uploaded the [modified package](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vvpjlbi4pqir3v5/oracle-java8-installer_8u0-1~webupd8~5_all.modfied.deb), but I highly suggest to use the original file and do the modification yourself, since you shouldn't install stuff by random people on the internet ;)